# MySQL - Add flag column to identify the first payment

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to improve my current query. So I have this table called `Incomes`. Where I have a `sourceId` varchar field. I have a single SELECT for the fields I need, but I needed to add an extra field called `isFirstTime` to represent if it was the first time on the row on what that `sourceId` was used. This is my current query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  `income`.*,
  CASE WHEN (
      SELECT 
        `income2`.id
      FROM 
          `income` as `income2`
      WHERE
          `income2`."sourceId" = `income`."sourceId"
      ORDER BY 
          `income2`.created asc
      LIMIT 1
      ) = `income`.id THEN true ELSE false END
  as isFirstIncome
FROM 
  `income` as `income` 
WHERE `income`.incomeType IN ('passive', 'active') AND `income`.status = 'paid'
ORDER BY `income`.created desc
LIMIT 50
```

The query works but slows down if I keep increasing the `LIMIT` or `OFFSET`. Any suggestions?

UPDATE 1:
Added WHERE statements used on the original query

UPDATE 2:
MYSQL version 5.7.22

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using [Ordered Analytical Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html).

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` or `RANK` to get the desired result.

Below query will give the desired output.

```
SELECT *,
       CASE
         WHEN Row_number()
                OVER(
                  PARTITION BY sourceid
                  ORDER BY created ASC) = 1 THEN true
         ELSE false
       END AS isFirstIncome
FROM   income 
WHERE incomeType IN ('passive', 'active') AND status = 'paid' 
ORDER BY created desc
```

DB Fiddle: [See the result here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b17ed56b0bd8d8d172a18a9958d2ad5a)

Comment: Hi @abinash what if I need to add more filters on where statements, like instead of looking by `ownerId` I do something like `WHERE incomeType in ('passive', 'active') AND status = 'paid'`? I tried adding those fields into `PARTITION BY` and after some offset number it returns empty,

Comment: @Ellebkey Required filter can be added in `WHERE` condition. `PARTITION BY` clause is only for the column on which you want to calculate the firstIncome flag. As per your problem statement you wanted the `firstIncome` flag on the basis of `sourceId`, so only this column needs to be in the `PARTITION BY`.

Comment: Now the question is whether you need `ownerId` in `PARTITION BY` or not. Let say you have multiple ownerId in the table, do you still want the `firstIncome` flag based on sourceId or you want the firstIncome flag for each ownerId and sourceId. `PARTITION BY` clause should include all the columns on which you want to calculate the flag, `WHERE` condition is just for the filter on dataset.

Comment: Hi, I only need by `sourceId` my question was related because in your previous example I saw `ownerId` on the `PARTITION BY`. I'll do further testing with all  WHERE statements that I'm using

Comment: You left out the LIMIT.  Note that the query will, I think, do the `OVER` for all rows before realizing that it is needed for only 50.  _This_ may be the bulk of the performance problem.

Comment: I think the `DISTINCT` will lead to incorrect results.  Also, it requires an extra pass over the intermediate table.

Comment: Syntax error:  Don't use quotes around column names, use backtics.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is that `isFirstIncome` should be an extra column in the table.  It should be populated as the data is inserted.

If you don't like that, let's try to optimize the query...

Let's avoid doing the subquery more than 50 times.  This requires turning the query inside-out.  (It's like "explode-implode", where the query gathers lots of stuff, then sorts it and throws most of the rows away.)

To summarize:

1. do the least amount of effort to just identify the 5 rows.
2. JOIN to whatever tables are needed (including itself if appropriate); this is to get any other columns desired (including `isFirstIncome`).

   ```
   SELECT i3.*, 
          ( ... using i3 ... )  as isFirstIncome
      FROM (
        SELECT i1.id, i1.sourceId
            FROM  `income` AS i1
            WHERE  i1.incomeType IN ('passive', 'active')
              AND  i1.status = 'paid'
            ORDER BY  i1.created DESC
            LIMIT  50
           ) AS i2
      JOIN income AS i3  USING(id)
      ORDER BY i2.created DESC    -- yes, repeated
   ```

(I left out the computation of isFirstIncome; it is discussed in other Answers.  But note that it will be executed at most 50 times.)

(The aliases -- i1, i2, i3 -- are numbered in the order they will be "used"; this is to assist in following the SQL.)

To assist in performance, add

```
INDEX(status, incomeType, created, id, sourceId)
```

It should help with my formulation, but probably not for the other versions.  Your version would benefit from

```
INDEX(sourceId, created, id)
```

Comment: Hi Rick, I tried to use your query but USING throws a syntax error. I'm using MySQL and I need to add that is version 5.7.22

Comment: @Ellebkey - What does the syntax error say after "... near" ?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.. using `income3` ... ) as isFirstIncome FROM ( SELECT `income1`.id,' at line 3

Comment: I replaced i1, i2, i3 with income1, incom2, income3

Comment: `near '.. using` -- two dots is a syntax error.

Comment: so I had correctly the query with 3 dots, so I don't think that's the issue.